# Facial landmark measurements using Google ML Kit face detection data

Tags: artificial-intelligence, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, facial-identification

I'm experimenting with creating a photo verification feature using [Googles ML Kit face detection library](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection) ([API reference](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/reference/swift/mlkitfacedetection/api/reference/Classes/Face)). I'm get the following facial data:

```json
{
  boundingBox: (rect),

  headEulerAngleX: (double),
  headEulerAngleY: (double),
  headEulerAngleZ: (double),

  landmarks: [
    {
      type: (bottomMouth, rightMouth, leftMouth, noseBase, etc etc),
      x: (int),
      y: (int),
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I calculate the distance between facial landmarks? I'm hoping with some measurements then I could compare with other facial data and see how similar they are. I assume I will need to calculate the distances between two landmarks whilst also considering the rotation of the head but I do not know the maths involved!

I realise it might be impossible to get measurement in millimetres without more data but hopefully I could make some relative landmark measurements such as the noseBase->leftEye is 56% of leftEye->rightEye (aka pupil distance).